# Why am I not seeing SciView in PyCharm Professional with a Scientific Project

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I am looking to switch to PyCharm Professional from Spyder in Anaconda to start using GitHub CoPilot and a few other useful modern tools. I'm doing this on modern Macs with Apple Silicon.

I thought that this should be relatively easy because of the SciView mode which would allow me to easily see plots and data structures. However, after installing the most recent PyCharm on my Mac I don't seem to see SciView; the plots window seems to be working in a reasonable way, but I can't see the data there. I can see the data based on the variables held next to the python terminal, but it's not quite as easy as SciView looked.

Does anyone know why I'm not getting the proper "SciView" interface, or how I can make that happen?

I've tried a number of things to get SciView to show up. I've followed the tutorial at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-tutorial.html And I've tried toggling the flag for "Show plots in tool window" in Tools > Python plots. I expected that one of these changes would bring out the SciView pane as shown in the tutorial, but I can only get "Plots" in the upper right panel. Also, not that the flag in preferences is Tools > Python plots, not Tools > Python Scientific as I see in some of the previously answered questions for this.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: [SciView is a feature exclusive to PyCharm Professional](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-tutorial.html). If you're using PyCharm Community it won't be available.

Comment: Yep -- I'm using PyCharm Professional. At least when I go to About PyCharm, it shows "PyCharm 2023.3.1 (Professional Edition)".

Answer (score 0):

I think it is removed via PyCharm devs. Below is the topic in jetbrains forums:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/15594817030418-Where-did-SciView-tool-window-go